# How to use data from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to read this data from a csv file (now it is not comma separated, but if it is a problem I can use comma beetween data)

```
name                                    week    number
E-mini S&P 500 Options                  ES        2
E-mini S&P 500 Weekly Options - Week 1  EW1       4
E-mini S&P 500 Weekly Options - Week 2  EW2       6
E-mini S&P 500 Weekly Options - Week 3  EW3       8
E-mini S&P 500 Weekly Options - Week 4  EW4       10
```

Once the data has been imported into Python, I would need to be able to use the value "week" and the value "number" separately and one row at a time.  The first column is useless to me, except to be sure to call "week" and "number" of the same row. From what I understand by looking on stackoverflow, I should use dictionaries, but I don't find how to import the data correctly and how to subsequently recall them.
Here is the code I'm trying to use and that is not working fine at the moment:

```
with open("Data.csv", "r") as csv_file: 
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter"\t")
for row in csv.Dictreare(csv_file):
print(row)
```

Comment: Glad to see that you've tried something. But can you explain "that is not working fine at the moment" -- what's the issue? Syntax? Logic? Runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep='\t')

df.to_dict()
```

Note: in parameter `sep` you can use others like `'|'` - `' '` - `';'` ...

Comment: Ok, but how can I use a value from this dictionary?

Comment: You can acess the value by key, like: dict['key']. Here you can understand: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

So you could use `np.loadtxt` for what you want:

```
data = np.loadtxt("Data.csv",dtype = str)
week = np.loadtxt(data[:,4]) # 4 corresponds to the number of the column "week"
```

You would get the whole column of week, same thing for number.

Keep in mind that python numbering of the columns and rows starts from 0.

Is that what you need?

Comment: Not working, I only have 3 columns on the csv. I also tried changing 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  in main:
    data = np.loadtxt("Data.csv",dtype = str)
    raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

Comment: try deleting the header from the file